# Launcher vanished after disabling Unity plugin

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, launcher

I unfortunately disabled The Unity plugin from CompizConfig, now the launcher is vanished.

I cannot re-enable the Unity plugin now, because no way for me to load CompizConfig again without the launcher.

Please suggest any way to overcome this problem.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1705874  post no #3

Comment: Yes, this thread is useful to overcome this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click & add a folder, click on the folder to open the File Manager, go to `/usr/share/applications`, from there you can start CompizConfig & enable the Unity plugin.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10554391&postcount=3) (Thanks @Raja)

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below to run CCSM.

Once it comes up you can re-enable unity plugin

```
ccsm
```